# useState only works with refreshing project by CTRL+C, I refresh my project on browser but useState don't work

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

The code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const [username, setUsername] = useState(String);
const [receiver, setReceiver] = useState(String);

const params = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
  axios.get('example.com/users').then(res => {
    setUsername(() => res.data.Username);
    setSession(() => res.data.Session);
    setReceiver(() => params.receiverParam);
    console.log(`author: ${username} receiver: ${receiver}`);
  });
}, []);
```

I have wanted print the console.log as expected, but the username and the receiver values printing as empty.